# Sort by Modification Time doesn't work

Tags: workflow, file-browser

I just created a file in my computer "test-color.png" that I would like to **Import as plane**. On my Mac, the file is the last one modified in the folder "other-fabrice":

[image]

However, when I click on "**Import > Image as Planes**", the first files are not the last files modified:

[image]
Sort by Modification Time is enabled

[image]

I thought that maybe it was showing me reverse order (earliest modified first) so I went to the end of the list.
It's also not there:

[image]

How do I use "Sort by Modification Time" to find this file?

Comment: Works on my end.. Try switching *Display mode for the file list* option to Long List and looking what modification time does Blender see for those files. Maybe try updating Blender although I don't think this didn't work as of 2.78

Comment: Newest modified files are at the top of the list - after folders, you are showing the oldest files at the bottom of the list. You can turn off the folder filter to see only files.

Comment: An you explain further? So it's a time related filter but the type of files has priority over the time modified?